# Write the SQL code that will list only once the Physician-Person appointments

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

Write the SQL code that will list only once the Physician-Person appointments. In other words it will not list twice an appointment between the same physician and person

Can someone help me solve this problem. Thank you

Here is my solution, but I am getting error.

```
Select Appointment.Appointment_ID, Physician.Physician_ID, Person.Person_ID From Appointment, Physician, Person;
From appointment
Where exists
(Select 'Appointment_ID' from Appointment where Physician.Person_ID = Appointment.Appointment_ID);
```

the link below shows you the tables and questions. currently working on question 15
https://www.urgenthomework.com/question/hlst-3320-health-database-applications-sql-assignment

Comment: there are two from also use proper join, and create some testdatqa to test your query

Comment: where do I use the proper join?

Comment: Two FROM clause. Intermediate `;`.

Comment: From Appointment  a iNNER JOIN  Physician ph ON a.Physian_ID  = ph.Physian_ID and that for all tables and remove the second FROM clause

Comment: « I’m getting error ». What error ?